# Simple C# connection to .accdb file

Tags: c#

All I want to do is to retrieve data from tables in .accdb file.

Here is my full application:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.OleDb;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            OleDbConnection myConn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:/Microland.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;");
            myConn.Open();
            OleDbCommand myQuery = new OleDbCommand("select CustID from Customers WHERE CustID = 1;", myConn);
            OleDbDataReader myReader = myQuery.ExecuteReader();
             if(myReader.HasRows)
             {
                myReader.Read();
                label1.Text = myReader.ToString();
             }
            myConn.Close();

        }
    }
}
```

I think I am missing some using at the very top or my code is somewhat broken becasue then I click the button1 the label1 text changes to System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataReader.

Also is this the correct way to connect to access data base (.accdb) Do I need to do [this walkthrough](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171893.aspx) in order for it to work or this is irrelevant to what I need to do?

Thanks for any information! Very appreciated

Answer (score 4):

When you call `myReader.ToString()` it returns a string that represents the current object. So "System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataReader" is exactly that.

It seems like you want the label to be equal to the data that's read. I'm not familiar with this reader in particular, but [refer here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbdatareader(v=vs.110).aspx) for documentation.

You'll need to call one of the `Get*()` functions.

Answer (score 0):

```
label1.Text = myReader["CustID"] as string; // if nullable field
```

Or

```
label1.Text = (string)myReader["CustID"] // if not null
```